# Animate toggled fixed-top navbar

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, navbar, mdbootstrap

Using the mdbootstrap I have navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg white">
```

And it is positioned like this:
[image]

While scrolling I add the 'fixed-top' class to the navbar with this script:

```
let nav = $('.navbar').offset().top;
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= nav)  {
        $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
    } else {
        $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
    }
});
```

This works but:
I want to **animate the transition** between the original and the fixed-top state. I tried with setting a transition time to .navbar{} but it does not work. Do I need to wrap the navbar into another div?

Comment: `let nav = $('.navbar').offsetTop;` get nav offsettop and depending on its value... do this.. `if ($(window).pageYOffset >= nav) {
        $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top');
    }` I hope you get offsettop like that.. lil weak in Jquery :D

Comment: Thanks for that. But I think you get the offset with offset().top; in jQuery.

Comment: oh ok.. give it a try.. if it works :) .. lemme know if it works or not :D

Comment: It works and sets the class like it should do. But there is still no way for me to animate the transition.

Comment: What kind of animation you need.. give me an idea so I can help you better

Comment: Currently it just instantly pops to the top of the page. I want it to expand until its just as wide as the screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170535/discussion-between-himanshu-bansal-and-trojan).

Answer (score 3):

```
let nav = $('.navbar').offset().top;
```

Make a variable to store the offset and then update the condition for setting `.fixed-top`

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= nav) { 
    $('.navbar').addClass('fixed-top'); 
}
```

**To animated:**

Add a new class along with `.navbar-default`, say `animate`

```
.animate{
    transition: top 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

it will add an *ease-in-out* animation to the navbar.

`1s` is the time for animation, you can increase or decrease depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks that helped to get the offset right but it is still not animated.